# Labels outside polygons in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-10.4

Why are my labels placing outside my polygons?

My other labels are placed inside their polygons.

I am using ArcGIS 10.4 for Desktop.

Comment: Could you provide a screen shot to show what you mean.

Comment: Hmmmm, I can't find and upload feature?  Here is the link on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/epold4gqty826po/LabelsOutsidePolygons.jpg?dl=0

Comment: "Wetland C" is in its polygon but the others are outside their polygons

Answer (score 6):

You can set the placement properties which should take care of this.  Go into your layer properties and click on the Labels tab across the top.  Click on Placement Properties... and then check the Only place label inside polygon box as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Should also check that label weight is set to High under Conflict Detection

Comment: Also using the Maplex label engine can offer some additional options for label placement, weighting, etc.

Comment: Use maplex.  It really should be the standard labelling engine.  It gives you much more control over labelling.

Comment: When I "Only place labels inside polygon" the 3 labels that were outside the polygon not disappear.  I will try Maplex, but I also am wondering - shouldn't the default be to place the labels inside the polygons - that is what happens almost always for me.  why is it different his time?

Comment: also the label is high.  When I try to use Maplex, I get to the Label Manager and see a checklist of all my layers.  the one I'm trying to fix is checked and I see each of the labels is checked in the "select symbology categories" box, but I don't see what to do next to get them to draw inside the polygons